# Modeling Rare Continuous Events

Tags: continuous-data, rare-events

There is extensive literature written on the modeling of rare binary events. Exact logistic regression, rare events by Gary King, and Firth method work well for binary outcomes. But what would you suggest for rare continuous outcomes?

Say, I have multiple sources of income (20,000+ sources). Taken separately, each source throughout a year generates profit only on rare occasions. Each source could have 362 days of zero profit, and 3 days of positive profit. The number of profit days slightly vary from source to source.

I have collected daily profit values generated by each source into one data set. It looks like pooled cross sections. This profit is my dependent variable. Independent variables associated with it are also continuous variables.

Can you provide me any hints of which framework to use? (I tried tobit model that assumes left censoring, but not sure if this is a good approach.) Can I still use Firth or rare events?